# Paste into next empty column in different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

my code aims to copy the same range from multiple sheets and paste the data from each sheet into the next empty column in a Combined sheet. My code copies from each sheet correctly, but pastes into the same column and overwrites the preceding paste.

Could someone please point out my error?

Many thanks!

```
Sub CopyToNextCol()

    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim NextCol As Long

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If Sh.Name <> "Master" And Sh.Name <> "Lists" And Sh.Name <> "Combined" Then

          NextCol = Sheets("Combined").Cells(, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

          Sh.Range("B2:B44").Copy Sheets("Combined").Cells(, NextCol)

        End If

    Next Sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Is cell "B2" populated on each sheet? Also, probably good to be explicit on the row: `Cells(, Columns.Count)` ----> `Cells(1, Columns.Count)`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen - that's it! If I include B1 (the column header) it works. My problem now is I am planning to use a different column header in the copied data!

Comment: @cdfj you dont need the header, you were missing the number "1" after "Cells(" so it should work on any sheet with any header. The 1 represents the Row you want to know what last cell to use.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Same Ranges From Multiple Worksheets

- The following example will copy the worksheet names (*"I am planning to use a different column header"* in the comments) in the first row and each range below it.
- `s` - Source, `d` - Destination.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyToNextCol()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Combined")
    Dim dCell As Range
    Set dCell = dws.Cells(1, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case sws.Name
        Case "Master", "Lists", "Combined"
            ' Skip (do nothing)
        Case Else
            Set srg = sws.Range("B2:B44")
            dCell.Value = sws.Name
            srg.Copy dCell.Offset(1)
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1)
        End Select
    Next sws

    'wb.Save

End Sub
```